# Exception in REST client: Unable to find a messagebodyreader of content-type application/json

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, rest-client

I am building a REST client for https web service. My code works in eclipse but fails with above exception when executed via JAR. Following is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(LoginName,Password);
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() 
{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) 
    {}

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) 
    {}

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() 
    {
            return null;
    }
};

ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));

ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient);          
    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(clientURI + tokenURL, clientExecutor);
   request.getQueryParameters().add("loginName", LoginName);
    request.getQueryParameters().add("operatorId", OperatorId.toString());
    ClientResponse<String> response;

    try 
    {   
        response = request.get(String.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != Status.OK.getStatusCode())
        {
            System.out.println(("Failure: HTTP Code : " + response.getStatus()));
        }

        token = response.getEntity().toString();

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.error(("Failed: Exception=" + e.getMessage()) +  " " + e);
    }
```

I am building my Jar using ANT build. I guess this issue must be related to JAR conflict.Following is the list of JARs I am using:

commons-codec-1.2.jar

commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

commons-io-1.4.jar

commons-logging-1.0.4.jar

httpclient-4.0.jar

httpcore-4.1.2.jar

jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar

jackson-jaxrs-1.9.9.jar

jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar

jackson-xc-1.9.9.jar

javassist-3.8.0.GA.jar

jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar

jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar

jaxrs-api-2.3.5.Final.jar

jboss-common-core-2.2.14.GA.jar

jboss-el-1.0_02.CR4.jar

jboss-logging-spi-2.0.5.GA.jar

jboss-transaction-api-1.0.1.GA.jar

jbosscache-core-3.2.5.GA.jar

jcip-annotations-1.0.jar

jettison-1.3.1.jar

jgroups-2.6.13.GA.jar

jsr250-api-1.0.jar

log4j-1.2.15.jar

mail-1.4.4.jar

oauth-20100527.jar

oauth-provider-20100527.jar

persistence-api-1.0.jar

resteasy-atom-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-cache-core-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-cdi-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-crypto-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-fastinfoset-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-guice-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.4.final.jar

resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-jsapi-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-links-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-multipart-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-oauth-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-spring-2.3.5.Final.jar

resteasy-yaml-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

scannotation-1.0.3.jar

Comment: please post the whole stack trace...

Comment: Adding detailed error message:  `org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json;charset="utf-8" and type null`

Comment: Tried adding following code snippet as well as mentioned in few other questions. But still issue persists. `ResteasyProviderFactory instance=ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance(); 
  RegisterBuiltin.register(instance); 
  instance.registerProvider(ResteasyJacksonProvider.class);`

Comment: For the solution to this problem refer to another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698417/how-to-set-classpath-order-while-building-jar-file-using-ant). Solution explained there.